# Odoo How to create Access Rule for Team Leader to visible all leads in team?

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-10

Do you know how to create the access rule for team leader to view all leads of members in team?

I try the following code but it doesn't work :(

Anyone have the solution for this already??

```
<odoo>
  <data>
    <record model="ir.rule" id="saleman_visible_lead">
        <field name="name">Saleman visible own lead / Team Leader visible all lead in team</field>
        <field name="model_id" ref="base.model_res_partner"></field>
        <field name="groups" eval="[(4,ref('sales_team.group_sale_salesman'))]"></field>
        <field name="domain_force">['|','|',('user_id.team_id.user_id','=',user.id),('user_id','=',user.id),('user_id','=',False)]</field>
    </record>
  </data>
</odoo>
```

Answer (score 1):

Feature you asked is already available in default odoo:

If you give `User: Own Documents Only` access user can see own lead only

If you give `User: All Documents access` user can see own ALL Lead

For more detail check below Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: That's seem correct ,but I want to access all lead in team not all lead in application.